# jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation does not respect mirroring?

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I'm using jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation to capture a still image from the front-facing camera on an iOS device (iOS 5.0).

I'm using a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to display the output of the front-facing camera prior to taking the image. By default, the display is mirrored, and I do not adjust this.

The still image that is captured is *not* mirrored (i.e. it is flipped about the vertical axis compared with what is displayed by the preview layer).  I want it to be mirrored. Any ideas how to accomplish that?

Here is the relevant code:

```
- (void) captureStillImage {
    AVCaptureConnection *stillImageConnection = [stillImageOutput connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];        
    UIDeviceOrientation curDeviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    AVCaptureVideoOrientation avcaptureOrientation = [self avOrientationForDeviceOrientation:curDeviceOrientation];
    [stillImageConnection setVideoOrientation:avcaptureOrientation];

    [stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:AVVideoCodecJPEG 
                                                                    forKey:AVVideoCodecKey]]; 

    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:stillImageConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {            
            NSData *jpegData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:jpegData];
            [self showImage:image];
        }                        
    }];
}
```